# Adding a Second Service with AWS Copilot

Tags: amazon-ecs

I've very familiar with doing all of this (quite tedious) stuff manually with ECS.

I'm experimenting with Copilot - which is really working - I have one service up really easily, but my solution has multiple services/containers.

How do I now add a second service/container to my cluster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: change to your second service's code directory and run `copilot init` again! If you need to specify a different dockerfile, you can use the `--dockerfile` flag. If you need to use an existing image, you can use `--image` with the name of an existing container registry.

Long answer:
Copilot stores metadata in SSM Parameter Store in the account which was used to run `copilot app init` or `copilot init`, so as long as you don't change the AWS credentials you're using when you run Copilot, everything should just work when you run `copilot init` in a new repository.

Some other use cases:

If it's an existing image like redis or postgres and you don't need to customize anything about the actual image or expose it, you can run

```
copilot init -t Backend\ Service --image redis --port 6379 --name redis
```

If your service lives in a separate code repository and needs to access the internet, you can cd into that directory and run

```
copilot init --app $YOUR_APP_NAME --type Load\ Balanced\ Web\ Service --dockerfile ./Dockerfile --port 1234 --name $YOUR_SERVICE_NAME --deploy
```

So all you need to do is run `copilot init --app $YOUR_APP_NAME` with the same AWS credentials in a new directory, and you'll be able to set up and deploy your second services.

Copilot also allows you to set up persistent storage associated with a given service by using the `copilot storage init` command. This specifies a new DynamoDB table or S3 bucket, which will be created when you run `copilot svc deploy`. It will create one storage addon per environment you deploy the service to, so as not to mix test and production data.

Comment: For anyone following - this is an important point that the config is in SSM - the manifest files don't have to be in a single "project"

Comment: is it possible to share the same S3 bucket between two services?

Comment: For those interested in sharing S3 buckets, see our response to @renatogbp on Github: https://github.com/aws/copilot-cli/issues/2138

Comment: @AustinEly I am trying to bring up a Celery service in a Django app. Can you please suggest how can I achieve this in copilot?